# Dicionário em python

Tags: python

Seguinte, tenho uma tabela com palavras em uma língua, vou usar exemplo para supor, do português para o inglês. Essas palavras estão em um dicionário onde a chave é a palavra em português e o valor é a palavra em inglês. Utilizando as chaves do dicionário em uma string, formando uma frase, como seria traduzido para o inglês? Ou seja como eu inputo uma frase e me retorna o valor dela? *Vamos considerar que seria uma frase e não apenas uma palavra... estou tentando passar para uma lista para fazer a leitura.

Comment: Não vou conseguir dormir, alguém ajuda por favor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que eu percebi acho podes fazer o seguinte:

```
d = {'olá': 'hello', 'como':'how', 'estás':'are', 'tu':'you'}
frase = 'olá como estás tu' # aqui seria o teu input('frase')
words = frase.split() # dividir por espaços para obter uma lista com as palavras
print(' '.join(d[w] for w in words)) # hello how are you
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MIQw)

Uma versão melhor preparada, com a capacidade de contornar possíveis erros de chaves (*KeyError*):

```
d = {'olá': 'hello', 'como':'how', 'estás':'are', 'tu':'you'}
frase = 'olá como estás tu aí em cima' # aqui seria o teu input('frase')
words = frase.split() # dividir por espaços para obter uma lista com as palavras
print(' '.join(d[w] if w in d else w for w in words)) # hello how are you aí em cima
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MIRj)

Nesta útima versão caso a palavra em português não exista no dicionário simplesmente não a traduz.

Por comentários percebi que talvez queiras frases inteiras como chaves, isso ainda é menos trabalhoso:

```
d = {'olá como estás?':'Hello how you', 'grande almoço': 'nice lunch'}
hey = 'olá como estás?'
print(d[hey]) # Hello how you
hey = 'grande almoço'
print(d[hey]) # nice lunch
hey = 'hey hey hey'
if hey not in d: # não exiSta no dic
  print(hey) # hey hey hey
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MIRj/4)

Comment: explica uma coisa, sou novato em *Python*, você está fazendo  o contrário, tipo valor ~> chave ?

Comment: Olá @WéllingthonM.deSouza , não, o rapaz que fez a pergunta diz "... onde a chave é a palavra em português ", ou seja, `{chave1: valor1, chave2: valor2}`

Comment: Sim, entendi, mais para traduzir do `Inglês` para o `Português`

Comment: Não @WéllingthonM.deSouza, o que é dito na pergunta é "Essas palavras estão em um dicionário onde a chave é a palavra em português e o valor é a palavra em inglês...como seria traduzido para o inglês? "

Comment: Obrigado, mas vocês pensaram em uma palavra composta tipo "com licença" ser traduzida apenas para uma palavra?

Comment: @Amador.py ,deves saber com antecedência se é para traduzir por palavra ou por frase (pox ex: dividir por ponto). Fazer uma coisa como a que eu acho agora que queres não é trivial e exige muito estudo

Comment: Tem como explicar a última linha?! a função do 'join' e o porque 'd[w]'

Comment: @Amador.py, claro, mas não há nada melhor que ver. Esse `join()` do ultimo exemplo é equivalente a isto: https://repl.it/MIjC/1

Comment: Por frase @WéllingthonM.deSouza, acontece que tem algumas palavras compostas que traduzem para uma palavra só. Obrigado pela indicação

Comment: @Amador.py isso ainda é mais facil, podes logo fazer isto: https://repl.it/MIRj/3

Comment: Entendi mais da metade do código, só fiquei sem entender o d no índice w (d[w]), isso quando w ja estiver contido em d (w in d, foi aquele else). @WéllingthonM.deSouza grato

Comment: @Amador.py `d[x]` armazena o valor em `d` cuja chave é `x`

Comment: Não é você que vai definir as palavras / frases ? Veja: [repl.it](https://repl.it/MIDB/5)

Comment: Sim, tudo certo. Obrigado por compartilhar o conhecimento.

Comment: @Amador.py , estamos aqui para isso. De nada

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
dicionario = {
  'good morning': 'bom dia',
  'good night': 'boa noite',
  'Hello': 'Ola',
  'good': 'bom',
  'day': 'dia',
  'this': 'isso',
  'will': 'vai',
  'translate': 'traduzir',
  'word': 'palavra',
  'for': 'por'
}

def traduz(frase, dicionario):
    saida = []
    # Verifica se o dicionario contem a frase
    if dicionario.get(frase):
      traducao = dicionario.get(frase)
      saida.append(traducao if traducao else frase)
    else: # Caso nao tem, divida a frase em uma lista de palavras
      frase = frase.split()
      # Iterar as palavras de entrada e acrescentar tradução
      for palavra in frase:
          traducao = dicionario.get(palavra)
          saida.append(traducao if traducao else palavra)

      # Retorna saida
    return ' '.join(saida)
```

Para usar, chame o método

```
# Traduz a frase informada pelo usuario.
print(traduz(input('Digite uma frase: '), dicionario))
# Traduz a frase pre-definida.
print(traduz('good night', dicionario))
# Traduz palavra por palavra
print(traduz('isso vai traduzir palavra por palavra', dicionario))
```

> Esse resposta foi baseada através desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232877) no SOen.
>
> Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/MIDB/4)

Comment: O dicionário está com as chaves/trocados, o AP diz que as chaves são em pt

Comment: Ele supos que era `Português ~> Inglês`

Comment: Exatamente. Chave em português e valor em inglês. Veja na pergunta: "*[...] onde a chave é a palavra em português e o valor é a palavra em inglês*"

Comment: Obrigado, mas vocês pensaram em uma palavra composta tipo "com licença" ser traduzida apenas para uma palavra?

Answer (score 0):

Um pouco tarde, gostaria de adicionar a funcionalidade de procurar expressões prontas como 'bom dia'->'good morning' diferenciando 'Boa viagem'->'good trip', ou seja, ir além da tradução de palavra por palavra.

Basicamente temos esse dicionário:

```
dicionario = {
        'bom':'good',
        'boa':'good',
        'dia':'day',
        'bom dia':'good morning',
        'acordou':'wake up',
        'viagem':'trip',
        'filme':'movie',
        'apertem os cintos... o piloto sumiu':'Airplane',
        'assisti':'watched',
        'eu':'I',
        'nunca':'never',
        'o':'the'
}
```

Repare que tem até o nome de um filme.

Primeiro fazemos uma função que verifica se uma sequência ou palavra se encontram no dicionário:

```
def existe_traducao(dicionario, lista):
    sequencia = ' '.join(x.lower() for x in lista)
    if sequencia in dicionario:
        return dicionario[sequencia]
    return ''

>>> print(existe_traducao(dicionario, ['Boa']))
good
>>> print(existe_traducao(dicionario, ['boa', 'viagem']))

>>> print(existe_traducao(dicionario, ['bom', 'dia']))
good morning
```

Agora só precisamos traduzir a frase procurando se existem expressões. Para isso, percorremos da palavra atual até o fim, depois da palavra atual até o fim -1 e assim por diante procurando uma chave no dicionário:

```
def traduz(dicionario, frase):
    palavras = frase.split()
    lista_traduzida = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(palavras):
        for j in range(len(palavras), i, -1):
            traducao = existe_traducao(dicionario, palavras[i:j])
            if traducao != '': #Se achei tradução
                lista_traduzida.append(traducao)
                i = j
                break
        else:
            lista_traduzida.append(palavras[i].lower())
            i+=1
    return ' '.join(lista_traduzida)

>>> frase = 'Bom dia AlexCiuffa' #AlexCiuffa não está no dicionário
>>> print(traduz(dicionario, frase))
good morning AlexCiuffa
>>> frase = 'Boa viagem amigo' #amigo não está no dicionário
>>> print(traduz(dicionario, frase))
good trip amigo
>>> frase = 'Eu nunca assisti o filme Apertem os cintos... O piloto sumiu'
>>> print(traduz(dicionario, frase)) #perceba que a frase possui um titulo de filme
I never watched the movie Airplane
```